# Crawler keep on reload the same page

Tags: web-crawler

I try to crawl this site, beginning with the following page :
https://www.yachtshop.eu/fr/product/4262003/Passerelle%20hydraulique%20Bridge%2023%2012%20V

Navigate to data > I'm there >ok

Detect optimal settings > Detect optimal settings>Is the data you want to extract still in the browser >yes

Rows per page > Single

Then... nothing. The crawler keeps on reload again and again.

What's wrong ?

Comment: Do not crawl other's prices.

Comment: This is a technical question and this is a moral answer.